Problem with PSQL encoding of french in Windows cmd prompt
I've been struggling with PSQL and encoding in Windows cmd prompt for a while now and although I managed to make it work about 4 times with 4 different databases, it seems that every time the problem is the same, but the solution is different. I can't deal with it anymore.
I've tried this so far:
CREATE DATABASE test WITH OWNER admin
TEMPLATE = TEMPLATE0
LC_COLLATE = 'fr-FR-x-icu'
LC_CTYPE = 'fr-FR-x-icu'
ENCODING = 'UTF8' OR 'WIN1252'

I've played with SET client_encoding = 'UTF8' or 'WIN1252' which worked some times. I've put it in my create_tables.sql file just before creating the tables, and also played with it once the tables were populated in SQL Shell.
I've even added cmd.exe /c chcp 1252 to runpsql script.
I've also changed Windows' "Current language for Non-Unicode programs" hoping it will change something.
Usually a variation of these solutions would work, but for my current database that I am working on it just refuses to make any changes whatsoever and I am out of ideas.
Is there something I am missing or should I give up on windows command prompt and give WSL a try?

I am talking about the encoding of the data that I insert into my tables. The encoding is UTF-8, the database is also created with UTF8 encoding.
Here's what I get after I send a query: SavonÃ© or ConcÃ¢mbre
These words contain a french letter like à ô î é è ê ô û ù.

Are you talking about psql's error messages? Or abou the encoding of the data that you insert and select? What is the encoding of the data you insert into the database?

@LaurenzAlbe  I am talking about the encoding of the data that I insert into my tables. The encoding is UTF8, the database is also created with UTF8 encoding.
Here's what I get after I send a query:
-SavonÃ© -ConcÃ¢mbre
These words contain a french letter like à ô î é è ê ô û ù

Based on the data you are showing, the problem is your client_encoding. You have to set that to UTF8, so that PostgreSQL interprets the data as UTF-8. There are several ways to set the client encoding:

run the SQL statement
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';

or equivalently
SET NAMES 'UTF8';


set the environment variable PGCLIENTENCODING to UTF8

in psql, you can set
\encoding UTF8



That will make sure that the data in your database are correct.

There is another aspect that is Windows-specific; see the documentation:

psql is built as a “console application”. Since the Windows console windows use a different encoding than the rest of the system, you must take special care when using 8-bit characters within psql. If psql detects a problematic console code page, it will warn you at startup. To change the console code page, two things are necessary:

Set the code page by entering cmd.exe /c chcp 1252. (1252 is a code page that is appropriate for German; replace it with your value.) If you are using Cygwin, you can put this command in /etc/profile.

Set the console font to Lucida Console, because the raster font does not work with the ANSI code page.



This has nothing to do with what is stored in your database, but it will make sure that the data are displayed correctly on the Windows command line.

Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately this did not solve the problem. Nothing changed, basically. I've tried everything except changing the console font, but I doubt that will help in this case. Let me know if I can give you any additional information that would help you.

I am pretty certain that my answer is the right one. SavonÃ© is exactly what you get if you store Savoné, encoded in UTF-8, in the database while the client_encoding is WIN1252. Of course, changing the client encoding won't fix the data that are already stored in the database in a corrupted way. But any new data that you insert while the client_encoding is set to UTF8 will be correct.

I tried setting client_encoding to UTF8 then manually added a new entry into the table.I got this error: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe9 0x6c 0xe9.I then switched client_encoding to WIN1252 and attempted to add the entry once again, and not only did this fix work, but it appears the previous entries were fixed as well.

I recreated the database, tried the same method again and now only the new added entry was fixed. I can't seem to find a way for my seed table to be added with the proper encoding. Adding SET client_encoding = WIN1252 in the .sql file before inserting into tables is not working.

Yes, because that is wrong. Like I said in my answer, you must set client_encoding to UTF8 if that is the encoding of the data.

SET client_encoding = UTF8 does not work either though.
The only way so far is to type  SET client_encoding to WIN1252 then manually insert into table. The new entry will be displayed with the proper encoding, but not the previously added ones.

Then the data are not in UTF-8. It is simple: you have to figure out in which encoding the data in the INSERT statements are and set client_encoding to that value.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
